"Brass neck of her. Spoilt rotten, her."
On TV, a woman who doesn't like another woman's behaviour, talks behind her when she goes away . She says:
- Brass neck of her.
- Spoilt rotten, her. Coronation Street (see: 1:48-1:55)
As far as I understand, she thinks that the other woman is overly confident, cheeky, etc.
I checked the subtitles, and something caught my attention.
Sentences are different in stucture; one is with "of", the other is without "of". In the first sentence, she says "[negative behaviour] of her", but in the second one she says "[negative behaviour], her." (without of and with a comma)
Why is that?

Brass neck  is a noun. Spoilt rotten is an adjectival phrase.

...and in more standard English it would be "[She's] spoilt rotten, she is".

@KateBunting, and in more standard English, the first one would be "[She has] a brass neck.", wouldn't it? Or maybe, "A brass neck, she has." Is that correct?

To  preserve the exclamatory style - "The brass neck of her!" or "What brass neck she has!"

There are no "sentences", there are a couple of phrases and you need to use context to understand what's going on
The first is "spoiled rotten" (an idiomatic colocation) and we understand this to mean "She is spoiled rotten", (ie she is rude because she always gets what she wants).  Then "Her" is a separate utterance used to emphasise that the first is about "her".  It isn't grammatically linked to the first.
You do sometimes see this in situations in which a subject and verb has been omitted, but then the speaker feels the need to clarify what the subject is.  It may be more common in some dialects - these characters are speaking in informal Manchester dialect.

super smart, that one.  (instead of "that one is super smart")

or from a sketch

Camelot?!... Very good pig country, Camelot...

The first is different. I'd understand it to be reduced from "The brass neck of her is .....". Again you this seems more common in some dialects, but I could imagine exclamations like "The size of it!" when looking at something very large.  It means "cheekiness".  And so I'd guess that is the context.

The characters are speaking jn informal Manchester regional dialect (says my wife from Wigan).

@James K, I understand the second one. As for the first one, doesn't' "Brass neck of her" has the same structure as "That is very kind of her." or "That is very good of you?" meaning "She is very kind." or "You are very good."?

@Yunus - no. It has the same structure as 'height of him' (of a tall man).

There’s also the exclamation The nerve!. (Perhaps that’s more American than British? I guess Brits might be more likely to use cheek?)
